# Transferring intent/ data/ bundle between parent/otherwise activity and fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have three classes here: Ijob, Tabbed_Activity and PlaceholderFragment. I want to pass the strings created in the Ijob class to my PlaceholderFragment onCreateView to show them as a custom page. I am yet to create a second and third fragment. Ijob is a list of jobs. Tabbed_Activity is the manager class of the fragments. PlaceholderFragment is one of the fragments. As you can see, I have tried bundle, intent and getActivity.. but none of them seems to work. I have also tried getting the data from Ijob to Tabbed_Activity first, then to PlaceholderFragment. Please help.

Ijob.java

```
package com.example.administrator.signin;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Ijob extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON

//  private static String url = "http://0.0.00.00:xxxxx/Transporter/fetch_ffa_insp_emp.jsp?ecd=5d573aecfdc5e7a5";

// JSON Node names

private static final String TAG_CON_NO = "CONSUMER_NO";
private static final String TAG_MET_NO = "METER_NO";
private static final String TAG_REC_ON = "RECEIVED_ON";
private static final String TAG_CON_NAME = "CON_NAME";
//private static final String TAG_CON_CAT = "CON_CAT";
private static final String TAG_MET_RAT = "MET_RAT";
private static final String TAG_CON_ADD = "CON_ADD";
//private static final String TAG_CON_ACC_ADD = "CON_ACC_ADD";
private static final String TAG_COM_RSN = "COM_RSN";

public static final String TAG_M_REF = "M_REF";
private static final String TAG_M_DATE = "M_DATE";
//  //private static final String TAG_CON_CAT = " ";
private static final String TAG_PREV_DATA = "PREV_DATA";
private static final String TAG_TELE_NO = "TELE_NO";
private static final String TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = "IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG";
private static final String TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM = "LCC_LRO_ROM";




// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jobList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ijob);

    jobList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {



            // getting values from selected ListItem

            String CONSUMER_NO = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CON_NO))
                    .getText().toString();
            String METER_NO = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MET_NO))
                    .getText().toString();
            String MET_RAT = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MET_RAT))
                    .getText().toString();
            String REC_ON = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.REC_ON))
                    .getText().toString();
            String CON_NAME = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CON_NAME))
                    .getText().toString();
            String CON_ADD = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CON_ADD))
                    .getText().toString();
            String COM_RSN = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.COM_RSN))
                .getText().toString();
            String M_REF = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.M_REF))
                    .getText().toString();
            String M_DATE = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.M_DATE))
                    .getText().toString();
            String PREV_DATA = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PREV_DATA))
                    .getText().toString();
            String TELE_NO = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TELE_NO))
                    .getText().toString();
            String IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG))
                    .getText().toString();
            String LCC_LRO_ROM = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LCC_LRO_ROM))
                    .getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tabbed_Activity.class);


        //  Bundle bundle= new Bundle();


        //  bundle.putString(TAG_CON_NO, CONSUMER_NO);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_MET_NO, METER_NO);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_MET_RAT, MET_RAT);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_REC_ON, REC_ON);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_CON_NAME, CON_NAME);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_CON_ADD, CON_ADD);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_COM_RSN, COM_RSN);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_M_REF, M_REF);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_M_DATE, M_DATE);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_PREV_DATA, PREV_DATA);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_TELE_NO, TELE_NO);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
        //  bundle.putString(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM, LCC_LRO_ROM);

        //  PlaceholderFragment argumentFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();//Get Fragment Instance
         //   argumentFragment.setArguments(bundle);//Finally set argument bundle to fragment */



        //    in.putExtra(TAG_CON_NO, CONSUMER_NO);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_MET_NO, METER_NO);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_MET_RAT, MET_RAT);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_REC_ON, REC_ON);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_CON_NAME, CON_NAME);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_CON_ADD, CON_ADD);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_COM_RSN, COM_RSN);
            in.putExtra(TAG_M_REF, M_REF);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_M_DATE, M_DATE);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_PREV_DATA, PREV_DATA);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_TELE_NO, TELE_NO);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
        //  in.putExtra(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM, LCC_LRO_ROM); */



            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}


/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Ijob.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String url = "http://00.00.00.00:00000/Transporter/fetch_ffa_insp_emp_1.jsp?ecd=" + aid;
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
//              JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray jobs = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
//              jobs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jobs.getJSONObject(i);

                    String CON_NO = c.getString(TAG_CON_NO);//  +" - "+c.getString(TAG_CON_CAT);
                    String MET_NO = c.getString(TAG_MET_NO);
                    String MET_RAT = c.getString(TAG_MET_RAT);
                    String REC_ON = c.getString(TAG_REC_ON);
                    String CON_NAME = (i + 1) + " . " + c.getString(TAG_CON_NAME);
                    String CON_ADD = c.getString(TAG_CON_ADD); //+" "+c.getString(TAG_CON_ACC_ADD);
                    String COM_RSN = c.getString(TAG_COM_RSN);
                    String M_REF = c.getString(TAG_M_REF);
                    String M_DATE = c.getString(TAG_M_DATE);
                    String PREV_DATA = c.getString(TAG_PREV_DATA);
                    String TELE_NO = c.getString(TAG_TELE_NO);
                    String IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = c.getString(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
                    String LCC_LRO_ROM = c.getString(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_CON_NO, CON_NO);
                    contact.put(TAG_MET_NO, MET_NO);
                    contact.put(TAG_MET_RAT, MET_RAT);
                    contact.put(TAG_REC_ON, REC_ON);
                    contact.put(TAG_CON_NAME, CON_NAME);
                    contact.put(TAG_CON_ADD, CON_ADD);
                    contact.put(TAG_COM_RSN, COM_RSN);

                    contact.put(TAG_M_REF, M_REF);
                    contact.put(TAG_M_DATE, M_DATE);
                    contact.put(TAG_PREV_DATA, PREV_DATA);
                    contact.put(TAG_TELE_NO, TELE_NO);
                    contact.put(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
                    contact.put(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM, LCC_LRO_ROM);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    jobList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Ijob.this, jobList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_CON_NO, TAG_MET_NO, TAG_MET_RAT,
                TAG_REC_ON, TAG_CON_NAME, TAG_CON_ADD, TAG_COM_RSN, TAG_M_REF, TAG_M_DATE, TAG_PREV_DATA, TAG_TELE_NO, TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM}, new int[]{R.id.CON_NO,
                R.id.MET_NO, R.id.MET_RAT, R.id.REC_ON, R.id.CON_NAME, R.id.CON_ADD, R.id.COM_RSN, R.id.M_REF, R.id.M_DATE, R.id.PREV_DATA, R.id.TELE_NO, R.id.IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, R.id.LCC_LRO_ROM});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}



}
```

Tabbed_Activity.java

```
package com.example.administrator.signin;


import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tabbed_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String TAG_M_REF = "M_REF";


    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);


    Intent in = getIntent();
    String MET_REF = in.getStringExtra(TAG_M_REF);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", MET_REF);
    PlaceholderFragment argumentFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();//Get Fragment Instance
    argumentFragment.setArguments(bundle);//Finally set argument bundle to fragment */


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).


        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

PlaceholderFragment.java

```
package com.example.administrator.signin;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 8/26/2016.
 */

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.placeholder_1, container, false);




   String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");


    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m_ref);


    textView.setText(strtext);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your are not using the placeholder fragment that is created in activity oncreate method no where else. You set bundle only here. PlaceHolderFragments created in viewpager dont have bundle. You have to set bundle in viewpager.

Comment: Where in viewpager should I create the bundle?